# How to parse output from diskutil activity in bash script

Tags: bash, diskutil

I want to be able to run a bash script over each line output from `diskutil` activity", I haven't been able to figure out how to do this though.

I thought maybe I could simply: 
`diskutil activity | xargs bash myScript.sh`

I have a feeling that `xargs` is just going to wait until `diskutil` activity is finished talking, which it will never do until you end the process.

Any suggestions on how I can execute a script per line of output would be appreciated!

Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The delay is probably due to buffering.

Try `xargs -L 1 bash myScript.sh` if you can process the data line by line.